# SPSS - Descriptive statistics of questionnaire items under categories

Tags: statistics, analysis, spss

I have a question and would like to know whether it is possible or meaningful to do the following.

I conducted a questionnaire about public transportation. Public transportation includes bus, tram and taxi. Under each type of transportation, there are 3 questions using five-level Likert scale (1 means 'strongly disagree' and 5 means 'strongly agree'). In total, I have 9 questions.
I received 100 responses and could summarize my data file as below:

- Bus: or *B* for short with 3 questions (3 items) and named them with variable names as *B1, B2 and B3*.
- Tram: or *T* for short3 questions (3 items) and named them with variable names as *T1, T2 and T3.*
- Taxi: or *TA* for short 3 questions (3 items) and named them with variable names as *TA1, TA2 and TA3.*

When I put everything in SPSS, it looks like:

```
No | B1 | B2 | B3 | T1 | T2 | T3 | TA1 | TA2 | TA3
1  | 1  |  2 | 3  |  3 | 2  | 5  | 2   | 4   |  2    
2  | 2  |  2 | 2  |  5 | 4  | 5  | 4   | 3   |  2         
3  | 3  |  5 | 4  |  2 | 2  | 1  | 5   | 2   |  3           
4  | 2  |  4 | 5  |  1 | 3  | 2  | 1   | 4   |  1   
5  | 2  |  4 | 5  |  1 | 3  | 2  | 1   | 4   |  1
.
.
.

100  | 4  |  3 | 4  |  3 | 4  | 2  | 2   | 4   |  2
```

---

Now, I could run descriptive analysis for each item, no problem. There is a separate descriptive analysis table for each item from *B1 ... TA3*.

However, I would like to know whether I could group *B1, B2 and B3*; and run a descriptive Analysis for *B* (representing *B1, B2 and B3*) to explore the level of agreement or disagreement of respondent to Bus in general? Does it make sense for me to run this kind of analysis? Or I could only run a descriptive analysis for each item?

Answer (score 1):

You could develop a simple sum index

```
comp bus=b1+b2+b3.
```

or calculate averages

```
comp bus=(b1+b2+b3)/3.
```

Then you could run the descriptives for the new variables.

Having said this, I would think there is a reason that you used 3 different questions for each mode of transport, so I would analyse them separately.

Building a "general" assessment with the indices above is a huge leap in theory that assumes that all 3 variables carry the same weight and are able to represent the assessment of the "bus in general". I did similar studies and my experience is that even with many more items you do not arrive there.

**A general assessment of something usually is a different beast and should be asked in a dedicated question.**